# Thread cannot bind a functor with template operator()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, functor

I'm having troubles with `std::thread`, which I think (from the error I get) is caused by `std::result_of` not liking my functor.

I would expect this to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct Foo
{
    template <class T>
    void operator() ( T& value ) // replacing T& by T fixes the issue
    {
        std::cout << "Foo output: " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto t = std::thread( Foo(), 42 );
    t.join();
}
```

but I get a compiler error (both g++ and clang++) saying:

```
(...) no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of<Foo (int)>'
```

As mentioned in the comment, replacing `T&` by `T` seems to correct the problem, can anyone please help me understand what's going on / what I did wrong?

---

**Edit**

Helping the compiler a bit by wrapping up my functor seems to work too:

```
auto t = std::thread( std::function< void(const int&) >(Foo()), 42 );
```

I just don't understand why this is necessary..

Comment: Your edit seems not right. Shouldn't it be `std::function< void(int&) >`?

Comment: @songyuanyao `operator()(T& value)` is callable with a `const int&` argument (`T` is deduced as `const int`). the problem is that `T&` cannot bind to rvalues that result from a decay-copy transformation that the constructor of a thread applies

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Could I encourage you to post an answer discussing shortly this idea of "decay-copy transformation" and the way threads handle their arguments? Your comment in nullstellensatz post seems to be the answer to my question.